# how to get the whole laravel language(localization) data onto view?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want to use the laravel language data at the frontend part in the browser.

So I can use [sprintf](http://locutusjs.io/php/strings/sprintf/) in js to show the same translation in frontend part.

I wish it could be an big javascript object. It would be very easy and nice to use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a situation I've dealt with myself and the answer is a bit awkward.

You can use `Lang::get('file')` to output the entire file as an array, which you can use with `json_encode` to do exactly what you want. *But*, as far as I know, you cannot get all language files. This probably has to do with the fact that Laravel cannot scan the directory for all file names without consuming a lot of disk resources, and does not do so normally. Language is handled with lazy loading in all applicable cases.

But! What you can do, is put all your JavaScript-related language in one file. I called mine `widgets.php`, and then do `json_encode( Lang::get('widget') )` to get your JavaScript relevant language in one object.

Or, if you really do need all of it, you can build it manually.

```
$lang = ['auth', 'validation', 'etc'];

for ($files as $file)
{
    $lang[$file] = Lang::get($file);
}

return json_encode($lang);
```

Comment: Thanks. I registered it in `AppServiceProvider.php` like this `view()->share('lang', Lang::get($lang));`, then I can use it in every view.

Answer (score 0):

I guess easiest way to do that is to use cookies. [Set coockie with Laravel](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/48/creating-a-new-cookie):

```
$cookie = Cookie::make($name, $value);
```

Then read and parse it with JS:

```
var x = document.cookie;
```